# Create a complex pattern on a face

Tags: mesh, modifiers, bevel, extrude, roughness

I have a sample like this, and I can't find out the method to create the bevel pattern around the circle

The most I need is your way to create it

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I'm partly posting this just to be a bit cheeky, however I think the point is still valid - Often when working with fine details (especially on glass objects), you may find it a lot easier to go very basic on the geometry, and then let materials do the work  for you (not saying that's necessarily the case here). Anyway, here's an example of how you can achieve a similar result with *very* simple geometry and a procedural (bump) material made within blender:

[image: Glass1]

[image: Glass2]

And yes, I'm aware my bottle has a square neck - that wasn't really the focus of my efforts ;)

Comment: Thank you so much, but I am begingner, so I think it's better for me with modeling from the basic objects. I want to improve the basic skills before applying shading notes. Thanks

Comment: Hey, no problem. It's just an example of what's possible.

Answer (score 8):

Create your shape, create rays around the center circle, select the circle and the rays you want:

[image]

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normals*. Once extruded, in the *Operator* box, enable the *Offset Even* option:

[image]

Add a *Subdivision Surface* modifier, create additional edge loops if you need to sharp some edges, etc

[image]

Comment: Thanks Moonboots, I will try your help. :)